# No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List when executing stored proc with parameters in EF 4.3

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Lately I've been working on stored procedure and encountered 1 strange problem.

First, I was able to successfully call a stored procedure from the database via:

> IList<XXXViewModel> XXXList =
>   _context.Database.SqlQuery("spXXX").ToList();

But when I needed to pass parameters it failed:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param1", param1Value));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param2", param2Value));
IList<XXXViewModel> XXXList =
_context.Database.SqlQuery<XXXViewModel>("spXXX @param1, @param2", parameters).ToList();
```

And I got the ff, error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter,
>   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native
>   type.

Note that I've also tried:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand<EXEC XXXViewModel>("spXXX @param1, @param2", parameters).ToList();
```

But got the same result :-(.

Also I've tried calling, by specifying each of the parameters:

```
IList<XXXResult> query = Context.Database.SqlQuery<XXXResult>("SP @paramA, @paramB, @paramC", new SqlParameter("paramA", "A"), new SqlParameter("paramB", "B"), new SqlParameter("paramC", "C")).ToList();
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to pass each parameter to the method (ie You can't pass a list)

```
IList<XXXViewModel> XXXList =
     _context.Database.SqlQuery<XXXViewModel>("spXXX @param1, @param2", 
     new SqlParameter("param1", param1Value), 
     new SqlParameter("param2", param2Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: It's now working, not sure have to define the type explicitly like: IList<Object> varName, using var varName = statement doesn't work :-?

Comment: You absolutely can pass a list, but you need to call .ToArray() on the list object

Answer (score 62):

In case someone else comes across this...

I created the parameters as a List and then in the SqlQuery call I passed it with a .ToArray(). Worked for me. Here's the modified code below...

```
var parameters = new List<object>(); 
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param1", param1Value)); 
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("param2", param2Value)); 
IList<XXXViewModel> XXXList = 
_context.Database.SqlQuery<XXXViewModel>("spXXX @param1, @param2", parameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 This definitely helped me using Database.ExecuteSqlCommand - it seems to want an array of objects, not an IEnumerable or anything else.

Comment: This helped me a LOT. :) Using Entity Framework Core though so I wasn't sure it was going to be the fix. I had been trying to pass an anonymous object as the SQL Parameter and kept getting a totally non-indicative error message, after trying the parameter list.ToList() it had another error but .ToArray() saved my day!!! THANK YOU EDYN!

Answer (score 6):

The solution for this problem (in my case was)

```
 var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeEntityType>(query, parms);
```

Where query was a string that had parameters inserted such as @Name etc.
The parms variable was a List of SQLParameters. SQL doesn't like generic lists....

SQL must have an array of SQLParameters sent as and object[] and not a list of generic type.

```
var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeEntityType>(query, parms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case parameter's `SQL type` and handling null values solved this problem. It was throwing same exception `No mapping exists from object type System.RuntimeType to a known managed provider native type.` for this also

```
var parameter1 = new SqlParameter("parameter1", typeof(string));
var parameter2 = new SqlParameter("parameter2", typeof(string));
var parameter3 = new SqlParameter("parameter3", typeof(string));

parameter1.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter1Value) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parameter1Value;
parameter2.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter2Value) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parameter2Value;
parameter3.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter3Value) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parameter3Value;
```

http://karim-medany.blogspot.ae/2014/02/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type.html

Answer (score 0):

didn't state SQL Server version, but Erland Sommarskog has an article on how to use Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET.

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Able to pass a variable amount of arguments from client using a single parameter.

Comment: Links in answers are welcome, but please make sure that your answer is useful without it. As it stands, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the stored procedure is only for update/insert, the following can be used as well.

```
string cmd = Constants.StoredProcs.usp_AddRoles.ToString() + " @userId, @roleIdList";
int result = db.Database
                        .ExecuteSqlCommand
                        (
                           cmd,
                           new SqlParameter("@userId", userId),
                           new SqlParameter("@roleIdList", roleId)
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dapper please check the Json serialize is properly added `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(**ClassName**)`

Answer (score -4):

You can also use string.Format to pass parameters to a stored procedure

```
string command = string.Format("EXEC spXXX {0},{1}", param1Value, param2Value);
IList<XXXViewModel> XXXList = 
  _context.Database.SqlQuery<XXXViewModel>(command).ToList();
```

Comment: This type, isn't a good way, to do that, never use `String.Format("")`, to make sql sentences, use Parameters methods instead! :D

Comment: Very bad solution, prone to sql injections, a great example of what people call an anti-pattern.

Comment: This is very bad This opens the possibility of SQL injections. Please remove this answer.