# Entity Framework Core - FromSql error:

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I am attempting to use Entity Framework Core to call a stored proc and get some rows back into objects.

Following examples from the solution I was working in I had everything in place but it isn't working correctly to call the stored procedure or map the results back.

This was from a piece of code:

`var list = this.context.DocumentList.FromSql<Document>("EXECUTE spSelDocsList @_iUserNumber", new { @_iUserNumber = UserId }).ToList();`

Returning error:

"No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type '<>f__AnonymousType23'."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for this error more and trying to determine why it was returned I figured this out inadvertently.

From this stack overflow post:
[No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List when executing stored proc with parameters in EF 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149919/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-collections-generic-list-when-executin)

Turns out that passing an anonymous object for the SqlParameter will lead to this No Mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type '<>f__AnonymousType23'.

The fix for this to the code was simple, first put the parameter in an actual SqlParameter object. But passing that SqlParameter object wasn't working so by putting that in a List and returning that ToArray() IS accepted by the EF FromSql method.

```
 List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
 sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@_iUserNumber", userId));

 var list = context.DocumentList.FromSql<Document>("EXECUTE spSelDocsList @_iUserNumber", sqlParameters.ToArray()).ToList();
```